# How to improve Unity Android game working too slow

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was making a unity game and for the moment it has just a couple of triangle objects chasing around the player triangle...
I implemented post processing...
Its a 2D game btw...
But the problem is, upon opening profiler, the GPU section shows no usage but the rendering section in CPU section takes up all the time...
I'm getting nearly 10fps consistently on my phone...
I'm getting 60 fps consistently in computer and the profiler there shows proper distribution between CPU n GPU section...
I have attached the screenshot of profiler for my android device...
I'm beginner to game dev so help would be appreciated...
Thank You :)[Profiler while play testing in my phone... Its Samsung Galaxy A70 in case that matters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDa6f.png)

Edit: I fixed my issue...
It wasn't about Canvas exactly...
I mean I had an extra empty canvas by mistake, true, but I removed it and only got 15FPS....
So I did 3 things....
1.I reduced quality of sprites... (I had them more than required)
It took my game to consistent 30 fps in my phone and any other phone...
2.I enabled fast mode for all post processing effects
3.I set V sync to 60fps target...
It didn't work on my phone, I'm still getting 30fps constantly... It seems like Samsungs has implemented extra caping...
But it gave my friends 60 FPS so I guess problem solved for now...

I would like to thank those who answered or commented here
Oh I was a bit busy because of exams so I got caught up...

Comment: From what I am seeing in profile. It's caused by a constant update of UI. Can you provide more detailed profiler picture where first ***PostLateUpdate.PlayerUpdateCanvases** is not toggled? Need more info.

Comment: Thank you for help... I got the issue fixed out... But I never knew drawing even an empty extra canvas is so expensive... I removed n got 15 fps around.... Thanks 

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use this command

```
void Awake ()
{
   Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
}
```

On phone, game are capped to 30 FPS =)

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with multiple canvas then one thing you should be aware of that they are expensive unity has to draw whole canvas if you write one element of that canvas, multiple canvas means multiple draw calls, and can you provide more screenshots of your profiler's hierarchy section.